# Using mixed citation number styles in tufte-book

Tags: citing, natbib, tufte-book

I have a book written using `tufte-book` class where most citations are given in sidenotes and where the citation numbers are superscripted by default. However there are places where I would like the citation numbers to appear in square brackets, especially in captions of some figures where they are reprinted from other sources. However, I don't know how to accomplish this and the closest I can do is use `\citep` command with `\setcitestyle{numbers,square}`. The problem is that, it does not include the citation in the sidenotes and also may not adjustthe citation counter properly. However the citation do appear in the References page. What I want is that, for citation numbers that are in square brackets in the text, I want the numbers to appear normally in superscript form in the sidenotes along with the citation texts.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% Citations and references
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\setcitestyle{numbers, sort}
\setcitestyle{square}

\begin{filecontents}{a.bib}
@article{HapticsSurvey,
    author = {Bermejo, Carlos and Hui, Pan},
    date-added = {2023-09-10 19:00:06 -0700},
    date-modified = {2023-09-10 19:00:06 -0700},
    journal = {ACM Computing Surveys (CSUR)},
    number = {9},
    pages = {1--35},
    publisher = {ACM New York, NY},
    title = {A survey on haptic technologies for mobile augmented reality},
    volume = {54},
    year = {2021}}
@article{PulfrichThreshold,
    author = {Durai, C Vijay Reena and Rajendran, Siddhart and Webster, Michael A and Vempati, Sandeep and Bharadwaj, Shrikant R},
    date-added = {2023-09-10 12:48:28 -0700},
    date-modified = {2023-09-10 12:48:28 -0700},
    journal = {Vision research},
    pages = {85--93},
    publisher = {Elsevier},
    title = {The magnitude of monocular light attenuation required to elicit the Pulfrich illusion},
    volume = {187},
    year = {2021}}
@book{PalmerRadiometry,
    author = {Palmer, James M and Grant, Barbara Geri},
    date-added = {2023-09-10 11:13:21 -0700},
    date-modified = {2023-09-10 11:13:21 -0700},
    publisher = {SPIE press Bellingham},
    title = {The art of radiometry},
    year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is first line. \cite{HapticsSurvey}

This is second line. \citep{PulfrichThreshold}

This is third line. \cite{PalmerRadiometry}

\bibliographystyle{customv7}
\bibliography{a}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]